# What are the figures in the "Goodbye Donald Trump" video

Tags: united-states, building, brazil

I am trying to classify the figures in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZqu8ojifhU)

1. From 0:00 to 0:12 - Statue of Liberty
2. From 0:14 to 0:20 - Abraham Lincoln
3. From 0:22 to 0:24 - ?
4. From 0:25 to 0:33 - ?
5. From 0:42 to 0:45 - ?
6. From 0:47 to 0:50 - ?
7. From 0:50 to 1:00 - Mount Rushmore
8. From 1:00 to 1:04 - Christ the Redeemer (Rio de Janeiro)
9. From 1:11 to 1:15 - Two drawings of ?
10. From 1:29 to 1:35 - George Washington

Can you help me out filling the blanks?

Please don't close this just because one of it is a building. Most are historical figures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a picture search and isn't actually about history.

Comment: Move to Travel: SE? They do picture recognitions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**00:22 Washington Monument**
   https://www.nps.gov/wamo/index.htm
**00:25 Martin Luther King, Jr. Memorial**
   https://www.nps.gov/mlkm/index.htm
**00:42 Crazy Horse Memorial**
   https://crazyhorsememorial.org/
**00:47 La Ofrenda (1989). Mural painted by Yreina Cervántez. Located in Los Angeles**
   https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Yreina_Cervantez
**01:11 American Gothic**
   https://www.wikiwand.com/en/American_Gothic
**01:24 Whistler's Mother**
    https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Whistler%27s_Mother